# Is it possible to index cases of a switch statement in Js?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Lets say I have the following switch statement:
**build.js**

```js
const {exec} = require('./exec'); // from child_process
const workers = require('./workers'); // functions to make folders/files
const {html} = require('../snippets/html'); //- 
const {css} = require('../snippets/css');   // |
const {js} = require('../snippets/js');     // | starter files based on extentions
const {py} = require('../snippets/py');     // |
const {java} = require('../snippets/java'); // |
const {cpp} = require('../snippets/cpp');   //-

let build = (project, folder) => {
    switch(project) {
        case 'web':
            workers.buildFile('index.html', html);
            workers.buildFile('style.css',  css);
            workers.buildFile('script.js',  js);
            if(folder !== undefined) {
                workers.buildDir(folder);
                exec(`mv index.html ${folder} && mv style.css ${folder} && mv script.js ./${folder}`);
            }
            break;
        case 'py':
            workers.buildFile('main.py', py);
            if(folder !== undefined) {
                workers.buildDir(folder);
                exec(`mv main.py ${folder}`);
            }
            break;
        case 'java':
            workers.buildFile('main.java', java);
            if(folder !== undefined) {
                workers.buildDir(folder);
                exec(`mv main.java ${folder}`);
            }
            break;
        case 'cpp':
            workers.buildFile('cpp.cpp', cpp);
            if(folder !== undefined) {
                workers.buildDir(folder);
                exec(`mv main.java ${folder}`);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
// exports function later on
```

**cli.js**

```
const bldr = require('commander'); // commander.
const package = require('./package.json'); //package.json
const {build} = require('../src/worker/lib/utils/build'); // snippets from above
const worker = require('../src/worker/lib/utils/workers'); // makes files/folders

bldr
.action(() => {
        if(bldr.opts('f').filename !== undefined) {
            if(bldr.opts('p') === true) {
                worker.buildFile(bldr.opts('f').filename, () => {
                    if(worker.getExtention(bldr.opts('f').filename)) {
                    // ^---> problem
                    // filename = any single case in switch  --^
                    // statement
                    }
                });
            } else {
                worker.buildFile(bldr.opts('f').filename);
            }
        }
    })
```

Would it be possible to index over 'py', 'js', and 'java' etc. without having to make a manual array or compare them individually? My actual switch statement is getting really long really quickly, so it'll really help if there is a faster way to do it. If you need more information, here is the link to where all the code is on [github](https://github.com/GruelingPine185/UpKeepCLI).

Comment: Can you show the contents of all the `do something`s? There's almost certainly a better way.

Comment: Need more info. What would be the source of these keys then? They must come from somewhere.

Comment: hold on 1 sec. I'll update the post for you all

Comment: What do you mean by "index over"?

Comment: "*My actual switch statement is getting really long really quickly, so it'll really help if there is a faster way to do it*" - are you having a performance problem? No, it doesn't matter how long the statement is, for constant values the compiler can generate a jump table.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't want to have you all read a bunch of text that doesn't make make a difference to how the question is answered. I'm not too worried about performance as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the non-websnippet imports into an object:

```
const snippets = { py, java, cpp };
```

Then the non-web cases can be converted to a single section. The `switch` isn't needed, it's quite verbose and isn't helping you enough IMO.

```
let build = (project, folder) => {
    if (project === 'web') {
        workers.buildFile('index.html', html);
        workers.buildFile('style.css', css);
        workers.buildFile('script.js', js);
        if (folder !== undefined) {
            workers.buildDir(folder);
            exec(`mv index.html ${folder} && mv style.css ${folder} && mv script.js ./${folder}`);
        }
    } else if (Object.keys(snippets).includes(project)) {
        const fileName = `main.${project}`;
        workers.buildFile(fileName, snippets[project]);
        if (folder !== undefined) {
            workers.buildDir(folder);
            exec(`mv ${fileName} ${folder}`);
        }
    }
};
```

To add more non-web types, just add them to the `snippets` object.

Comment: It's getting late, so I'll test this in the morning. I'll mark it as an answer & upvote it then.